# Is it possible to use same theme for second store?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multi-website, symlinks

I have 2 stores, is it possible that can I alter my same theme for the second store?

```
Note :      Taken Symbolic (symlinks) link of my file such as,

            app,skin,includes,errors,lib,media,var
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. You can create different themes for same in same or different packages.

If you have different packages or themes you can define it store wise from `system -> config -> design`

[image]

- Example Store A - rwd (Package) themea (Theme name)
- Example Store B - rwd (Package) themeb (Theme name)

So the skin path will be like

- For Store A - `<Magentoroot>/skin/frontend/rwd/themea`
- For Store B - `<Magentoroot>/skin/frontend/rwd/themeb`

**Update**

You can change the following **web path** for per storeview if you want

[image]

Comment: Here I need same theme for my both stores, how can I do that.

Comment: Is possible same theme for my both stores

Comment: You can change webpath only for skin, js and media. Refer my updated answer

Comment: Which webpath i need to give. Make sure we are discussing the same theme for different sore.

Comment: eg.my theme name : gold, now could you pls give some example relate to my case.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Do you just want different skin, media and js folder for different stores?

Comment: I need the same theme for my store 2, how can i achieve it. And my store 2 completely different from store 1but the theme is same. I did symbolic links to the new folder and along with index.php and .htccess file. using this tutorial http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use same theme for second and more store just you have to change you package and add that name inside a  system->config->design add that details here.

Comment: Could you pls briefly explain, Eg. my theme name : gold, so what i need o do?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 2 stores, is it possible that can I alter my same theme for the second store?

Yes, you can alter the theme, but it will take affect on both of your stores. If what want specific changes you can create a new theme that inherits that your current theme.

Comment: Then how can i put my same theme?